# Does Dijkstra's algorithm with a priority queue handle destination not found?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, dijkstra

I know how the algorithm works -- but it seems like it would just bounce around in a loop endlessly when using a priority queue trying to find the destination node that cannot be found.

Does Dijkstra's algorithm handle the case where the node is disconnected from the graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each iteration, exactly one node is extracted from the priority queue, and it will never be added again. Therefore, the priority queue will eventually become empty, and the algorithm stops when that happens. If there is no path to the target node, the unreachable node(s) will have their predecessor pointers set to nil (which was their initial value).

The algorithm is usually formulated in one of two ways:

- Start by adding only the start node to the priority queue. In this case, the algorithm will stop when all reachable nodes have been found.
- Start by adding *all* nodes to the priority queue. In this case, when there are only unreachable nodes left in the queue, you will start extracting unreachable nodes, but each of them has a distance of infinity, so they will never contribute a shorter path to any other node.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! I think I might have misunderstood -- Djistraka's will actually finish but when you go to iterate "backwards" from the source, the predecssor pointers seem to point in a cycle. How does one solve that problem? I considered checking if destination was inside before running, or checking the length of the running path...

Comment: They don't; the predecessor pointers are initialized to nil (which does not mean that they point at themselves; they point nowhere).

Comment: If I have A -> B disconnected and then  D -> C disconnected and run the algorithm, will A not point to B, and then B to A? Or is this a fault of my implementation?

Comment: You iterate backwards from the destination, not the source.  If the destination is unreachable, its predecessor reference should still be nil when the priority queue runs out of nodes to process.

Comment: @VaughanHilts Your example doesn't tell me anything without info about what *is* connected, what your start vertex is, and what your destination vertex is.

Comment: @pjs I'm going to go read more... I'm saying A and B are connected in a cycle, and D and C are as well. The source is say "A" and the destination is say "D". I don't want to clog the comments. :)

Comment: @VaughanHilts Then in your example A will schedule a "departure" to arrive at B using the weight of the A-B edge.  However, B won't schedule "departures" to anywhere else - C and D are unreachable, and A is already labeled/completed so there's no point in going back to it.  Since there are no reachable unlabeled vertices, your priority queue is now empty and the labeling stage is complete.  Now you go to D and check its predecessor label.  That's still nil, so D was unreachable from A.

Comment: @pjs It seems that only works if you only populate q with the source ONLY. Maybe Wikipedia is throwing me off.

Comment: It's supposed to work if you put all the nodes in the queue too. What does your graph look like, and what are the resulting predecessor pointers?

Comment: @VaughanHilts I prefer the start-from-source version as cleaner and more efficient, but the all-nodes-in-queue version works as well.  Vertex A will pop off the queue initially, and all nodes reachable from A (i.e., B) will have their priorities revised.  B is next off the queue. Since neither C nor D are reachable from B their priorities remain at infinity.  From that point on, everything you pop is unreachable from A and will have infinity as an additive component of its priority, until the queue is empty and you're done.  If D now has an infinite priority that means it was unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short, it won't loop endlessly since Dijkstra is BFS (traverse level by level) + Greedy (relax the distance from previous level to current level), and it does **not** traverse back to the previous `level`. The algorithm will end when the queue is empty.

If the destination is not found, the algorithm should return -1 or null.

Comment: Well, the algorithm does not return numbers, null, or anything like that. I should be more clear. Dijkstra's itself does not loop endlessly, but the "previous" pointers seem to loop around each other endlessly!